# android jdbc can't create connection to mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm tryng to make a connection with an android application to a mysql database, i know a driect connection is not advisable but I can't use a web service. So I've choose jdbc to make this connection but it returns this error:

```
01-16 11:59:27.681 19064-19064/com.studente.myapplication E/MySQLError:: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

my DB helper class:

```
    private Connection con;
private ResultSet rs;
private static String TAG = "MySQLHandler";

public  MySQLHandler(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://den1.mysql5.gear.host:3306/pedibustest", "pedibustest", "Aq4T0zWZxf?!");

    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("MySQLError: ", ex.toString());
    }
}

public void testGetData(){
    String query = "select * from users";
    try{
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()){
            Log.i(TAG, rs.getString("user_name"));
            Log.i(TAG, rs.getString("password"));
            Log.i(TAG, rs.getString("indirizzo"));
            Log.i(TAG, rs.getString("nome"));
            Log.i(TAG, "\n");
        }

    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("MySQLError: ", ex.toString());
    }
}
```

I cant figure out why it's not working, i've added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to the manifest, but it still won't work.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16051552/5110595)

Comment: thanks it works!! i feel like a fool for not thinking about it.

Comment: thanks happy to help you.